# Class variable assignment in c++

Tags: c++

The commented part in the below code prints some ambiguous values.

The uncommented version prints:

```
1:one
```

It means if I assign values for class variables before adding the object to the vector, it prints the assigned value. But if I assign a value after adding the object to to the vectors, it doesn't print the assigned value.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<vector>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

class T
{

    public:
    string t;
    int n;

};

int main()
{
    /**
    std::vector<T>::iterator it;
    vector<T>li;
    it = li.begin();
    T t1;
    it = li.insert(it,t1);
    t1.n = 1;
    t1.t = "one";
    it = li.begin();
    T t2;
    it = li.insert(it+1,t2);
    it = li.begin();
    T t3;
    it = li.insert(it+2,t3);

    cout << li.at(0).n << ":" << li.at(0).t << endl;
    */
    std::vector<T>::iterator it;
    vector<T>li;
    it = li.begin();
    T t1;
    t1.n = 1;
    t1.t = "one";
    it = li.insert(it,t1);
    it = li.begin();
    T t2;
    it = li.insert(it+1,t2);
    it = li.begin();
    T t3;
    it = li.insert(it+2,t3);

    cout << li.at(0).n << ":" << li.at(0).t << endl;
}
```

In case of Java, it's not like that. Instead, the value would be printed regardless of assigning the member variables before or after adding the object to the vector. How can I achieve the Java like functionality?

Comment: What is the expected output at the cout? Your inserts are at different positions: [li.begin(), li.begin()+1, li.begin()+2]

Comment: You need to use references. `insert` is inserting a _copy_ of `t1` into `li`.

Comment: It would be simpler and more "natural" here (in my opinion) to use `.push_back` instead of the inserts. Also, I'm not seeing any code where you attempt to modify any items in the vector after they were inserted (in the second example).

Comment: @Veena : `In case of Java, It is not like that.` Not like what? I'm no Java expert, but i feel that this question could be made more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`struct` or `class` in C++ behave like any other types. They are just a group of types together. So when you declare `T t1;`, what the compiler sees is almost like

```
// grouped together in the name `t1`
string t;
int n;
```

So when you send `t1` in the vector, it does exactly what it does with a `int` in java, it copies it.

**What can you do against that?**

There is two solution. You can change the value of the `T` which is inside the vector like that:

```
li[0] = {"aString", 23}
```

Or you can insert pointers. Pointers are just like objects in java. In fact, object in java are pointer, but the value is hidden. It would look like this:

```
vector<unique_ptr<T>> li;

// make unique is just a wrapper around the new to make a std::unique_ptr
li.emplace_back(make_unique<T>("aString", 23));
```

I really recommend you to use `emplace_back` instead of an iterator and `insert`. It will make your code cleaner and faster.

Comment: Yes. But any type in c++ can be a pointer, you can have a pointer to `int` and treat your int like a java object. You technically just need to add a star to the type to make it a pointer, like `float* f = new float` or `T* t = new T`. Here the `unique_ptr` is a wrapper around a pointer to make your life easier with memory management. Without this smart pointer you need to manually free the memory.

Answer (score 1):

In the lines

```
T t1;
it = li.insert(it,t1);
```

you declare the variable `t1` and insert a copy of it into the vector, but what you *don't* do is initialize the variable before insertion, meaning the copy inside the vector will *also* be uninitialized.

When you later does

```
cout << li.at(0).n << ":" << li.at(0).t << endl;
```

you print out the values of the uninitialized copy in the vector, and that leads to *undefined behavior*. The contents/value of uninitialized local variables is *indeterminate* and will seem random.

The initialization you do of `t1` is done *after* it is copied for the vector insertion.

Comment: The op probably do understand that the insertion before initialization leads to undefined behavior. Please answer `In case of Java, It is not like that. How to achieve the Java like functionality?`